# Git attributes file setup

Tags: git, github

I am  trying to add attributes file in git repositories to treat binary files as text files for diff option on the GitHub. How can I make sure that everyone who clones my Repository has the attributes file same as mine. What changes do I need to make in git configuration for the same.

Comment: Isn't the attributes file just part of the repo?

Comment: Treating binary files as text files isn't always a good idea.  In some cases it will break the contents of the file as line endings get added.  I've recently had a project where all of the custom font files were broken because they were being treated as text instead of binary.  Be careful with this route if you do go down it

Comment: i want to be able to see the diff option on github for binary files, also I am using the repo .git/info/attributes file but the same is not available to people who clone the repo.cannot figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `.git/info/attributes` file, use a `.gitattributes` file in the root of your repo.